# How to determine server status?

Tags: ruby, shell, architecture

I have the following setup.

A webserver that is used for game menus, a game websocket client.
A database that is used to keep track of initiated games and users statistics and more.
A proxy connecting webclients to different game servers.
A server application that controls game dynamics.

These things are situated on different servers.

Sometimes the game server has gone down due unknown reasons. I would like to write a script or similar that would try to connect to the proxy to see if the server is responding. I will use this script to display server status in the game menus. How should I write this script are there any do's and don'ts I should be aware of? Is it a good idea to write it as a script that for instance writes server status to a file and then allow the reading of this file from http request? Is there a preferred language to do this sort of stuff?

What im looking for is not software. Im looking for ideas or opinions on how to write such software.

Answer (score 2):

This question should be on serverfault, under a *supervision* tag.
Take a look at Nagios and you're good to go for most of your need

Comment: I guess I should change the question a bit im not looking for software im looking to write software and I wanted input on ideas for how this software should be written.